# Controller existe mas a o Lumen diz que não existe

Tags: laravel, restful, lumen

Minhas rotas estão assim.
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/communities <- essa é a url que eu estou requisitando

```
$app->group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function($app) {

$app->get('/', 'CommunitiesController@index');

}
```

[image: Essa é o print do controller em seu devido lugar.]

Meu controller está assim

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Controllers;

use App\Models\Communities;

class CommunitiesController
{
    public function index()
    {
        return "Cheguei no Controller";
    }
}
```

Mas a mensagem que recebo na requisição é que

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
(1/1) NotFoundHttpException
```

Como Resolver?

Comment: Você acessou a URL `api/v1/communities`, mas no código definiu apenas `api/v1/`. Está correto? Não deveria ser `get("/communities", ...)`?

Comment: $app->get('communities', 'CommunitiesController@index'); adicionei isso e também continua dando erro... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Além da observação da rota que deve ser assim:

```
$app->group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function($app) 
{
    $app->get('communities', 'CommunitiesController@index');
}
```

falta a herança da classe [Controller](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers) para o seu código, a ***correção*** é essa:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Communities;

class CommunitiesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return "Cheguei no Controller";
    }
}
```

ou seja, o seu `ComunitiesController` faltou herdar [Controller](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers).

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Lumen - HTTP Controllers](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers)
- [Lumen - Basic Controllers](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#basic-controllers)
- [Site Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/)
- [Lumen - Documentação](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/)

Comment: Show cara... Muito bom, me ajudou bastante, Obrigado!